# Android 10, select a photo from the gallery

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

people. I'm trying to get a photo from the Android 10 gallery. But, it tells me that bitmap = null, code below, what's wrong?

```
    public void createIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
    }
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 29  ) {
                    this.bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                } else {
                    this.bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContentResolver(), uri));
                }
```

Comment: what is the value of `uri`?

Comment: can you tell me possible options if (uri == ) else .....or something similar ?)

Comment: You have -again- two ACTIONs in your intent. Confusing. Please use only one.

Comment: `ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContentResolver().... ` Nobody knows what is happening here without the used code. It is strange that you would need to create a source where you have an uri for the chosen image.

Comment: What is strange? I need convert bitmap to mat

Comment: Code works fine for Android <= 9 but for Android >= 10 it is fail

Comment: blackapps can you please tell me what are you mean  'You have -again- two ACTIONs in your intent.' ?)

Comment: Do i have to explain the again? Or the two actions?

Comment: blackapps Intent code example please?)

Comment: `I need convert bitmap to mat` ? I dont see that in your code. Or is createSource doing that? You still did not post that code so nobody knows where you are up to.

Comment: add to this code Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, source); error bitmap null tomorrow I will write more now I do not have access to the device

Answer (score 1):

This is working on Android 10 also for me.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String imagePath =  getPath(data.getData());
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(imagePath),
                null, options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error loading the bitmap from the path: "
                + imagePath, e);
    }
  }

 private String getPath(Uri uri) {

    String path = "";
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                null);
        if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            path = "";
        } else {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, akhil nair. Android studio tells me that DATA is deprecated, and is it good to use MediaColumns.DATA?)

Comment: @OleksandrHadzhy Did this solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I have created the solution.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         uri = data.getData();
        InputStream stream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

}
```

This code works for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 29 and for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29